# VAT on Payment option on OpenERP 7.0

Tags: openerp, erp

I need the option of VAT on Payment on both customer invoices and suppliers invoices.
I checked the module vat_on_payment but it is available only for OpenERP6.1 and I couldn't insatll it on OpenERP7.0.
Is this option available on OpenERP7.0?
Is there a module designed for OpenERP7.0 that can do this?
Or is there a country specific module that is able to give this option?
If I need to create my own module where should I start? Any doc about this?
Thanks

Comment: We just published a funding campaign to port account_vat_on_payment to OpenERP 7.0. See it at http://igg.me/at/openerp-7-account-vat-on-payment/x/2728973